# MySQL: storing Amazon.com's order numbers that includes hyphens

Tags: mysql

I have a problem where I need to store Amazon.com's order numbers into a MySQL table. Amazon.com order numbers are composed of numbers and hyphens, like 102-1234567-1234567 (17 numbers and 2 hyphens). I've seen this "number" stored as a string because of the hyphen in some instances, and, subsequently, a search on this column is a string search instead of a numerical search.

Right now, I'm just storing them as VARCHAR(19), but is there a way to store this so that it's more efficient and faster in storing and retrieving? For example, I thought about parsing each numeric segments into one column of its own (3 columns total for one order "number") and doing `... WHERE colA=102 AND colB=1234567 AND colC=1234567` to pull up a particular order, instead of doing `...WHERE col LIKE '102-1234567-1234567'`. I know the former uses a lot less bytes, but is that also faster? The table I'm working on has over 100K rows and it grows by a tiny fraction every day.

Any suggestions or comments on how I should modify the structure or how I shouldn't? TIA!

Comment: Thank you for all of your great answers. I'll make it VARCHAR(X), where X>19, index this column, use `=` in instead of `LIKE`, although I will need to read up on the benefit. I'm not familiar with the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't separate the three numeric looking pieces of Amazon's current order number. Your database engine is fast enough to find an order by this number when its column is properly indexed. I get the 'premature optimization' sense from your question here.

Consider these suggestions:

- widen your column to `varchar(100)` or something larger than 19. You're dependent on the vendor, and making a big assumption that their structure will never change.
- put an index on this column. 100K rows is a very small dataset.
- find equality, rather than likeness as you're currently doing.   `WHERE Order='123-456-234`

Answer (score 3):

These order numbers are not in fact numbers. These are strings, and as such, should be stored as strings.

I don't know details of Amazon's orders, but if they're always 19 char long, you could use CHAR(19) instead of VARCHAR(19) as well as use ASCII charset instead of any multibyte. That should make it a little bit faster. Also creating an index that will cover the column entirely (i.e. length 19) might also help in performance, as well as using `=` instead of `LIKE`.